# How can I look up a TimeZone object from its short name on Android?

Tags: android, timezone

On Android, I need to parse timestamp strings that include a short timezone name, for example `2013-08-16 17:36 PDT`.  I am using a regular expression instead of SimpleDateFormat because the input strings can be have optional seconds and milliseconds.

Everything is working except for the timezone parsing: I can't figure out how to look up the time zones.  `TimeZone.getTimeZone()` explicitly does not support short timezone names like "PDT".  Yet I know the short names are in the system, because SimpleDateFormat can recognize a string like the above (the format would be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z`).

I recognize that there are some ambiguous timezone names (like "CST"), so using short names is not generally robust.  Nonetheless, I need to parse these timestamps.

Is there a way to look up TimeZone objects (or GMT offsets) from short timezone names on Android?

Comment: I believe you'd be better off just using multiple SimpleDateFormats (depending on the optional bits) and trying each one. :-/

Comment: Android is an operating system, not a language.  I assume you mean Java??